# htaccess rewrite executing script on server before delivering completely different script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess for my /mobile directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have in my index a mysql query which increments page counts basically and when i open m.mysite.net/style.css (which is /mobile/style.css) it executes index.php on the server but still delivers style.css without a problem... Why is it executing index.php if style.css is a locate-able file??

Here is the apache configuration for the directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/mobile
     ServerName m.mysite.com
     ServerAlias m.mysite.net
</VirtualHost>
```

How can i avoid executing any scripts and just deliver absolute files?
what do i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess seems to be correct. style.css should be passed without index.php.

But. You could have images inside your css, something like

```
background: url(/img/still/not/exists.png)
```

This images could be missing, and you have index.php call.

Anyway it is a guess of course :)